# Why to use CSS pseudo-elements "before" and "after" instead of just span tags?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I did research on it and as far as I know - CSS pseudo-elements ::before and ::after behaves like just span tags nested in a parent element.

On the other hand I have read they are might be extremely useful and in some cases even indispensable. If that is true they need to have some additional or different behavior than just span tags nested into the parent element.

If so what are the pros for using them over span tags?

Answer (score 6):

The most common use of `::before` and `::after` selectors is to add content to an element solely via CSS, without the need to change the HTML itself. This may be required in situations where you can’t change the HTML, or for semantic reasons.